# pandas.get_dummies converts float64

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas.get_dummies to convert some of my categorical variables before using tpot. My problem is I have a continuous variable, time, for example, and it is being converted to categories even though it is a continuous variable. This doesn't seem to happen in all cases, but I can't figure out when it occurs.

I tested the following:

```
pd.isnull(my_dataframe).any()
```

and all the categories say false

```
print(type(features[0,5])) # the time category with my continuous variable
```

and the output is 
`<class 'numpy.float64'>`

However when I do

```
df_dummies=pd.get_dummies(my_dataframe)
df_dummies.columns
```

It creates a column for each value of my time feature.

Like this: 'Time (min)_2', 'Time (min)_3',
       'Time (min)_4', 'Time (min)_5', 'Time (min)_6', 'Time (min)_10',
       'Time (min)_15', 'Time (min)_16', 'Time (min)_20', 'Time (min)_25',
       'Time (min)_30'

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked that your time features are inferred as datetime objects rather than strings?

Comment: How do I check that? If it is type float, could its still be inferred as a string?

Comment: when I add this line: my_dataframe["Time (min)"]=my_dataframe['Time (min)'].astype(np.float64), it fixes my issue. But I don't understand why it happens in the first place if the type is float64 to begin with

Comment: Just check `my_dataframe.dtypes` before calling `pd.get_dummies`. The dummies function shouldn't affect floats, datetime fields or ints. So my guess is that the columns you see being affected have been accidentally cast to strings somewhere along the line.

Comment: My time category shows type object right before the get_dummies command but is still split up. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your time category looks like it has been accidentally cast to a `str` somewhere along the line.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':np.random.choice([1, 2], 12),
                   'date':pd.date_range(start=datetime.now(),
                                        periods=12, freq='1min'),
                   'baz': np.linspace(0, 1, 12)})
df.dtypes
df_cast = df.copy()
df_cast['date'] = df_cast['date'].astype(str)
df_cast.dtypes
```

**Output**

```
foo      object
date     object
baz     float64
dtype: object
```

You can verify that the behaviour of `pd.get_dummies` with `df_cast` is consistent with what you're experiencing, and that it correctly handles `floats`, `ints` and `datetime` objects before any of the fields are cast to a `str`.

Comment: When you say accidentally, does that mean because of something in pandas? Because I don't see how it could be anything in my code.

Comment: Quite likely. One common culprit is reading from file. If you don't give pandas the explicit dtype, it will infer datetime fields from file as strings. You can double check this by writing `df` to csv and reading it directly back in.